# Vertical alignment tableless

Tags: css

I have 3 columns field, first 2 columns is the description and the last column is the image. Is there a way to vertical align the description according to the height of the image. I could not specify the line height since the height of the image will vary. Currently, if I use table then there is no problem. But what I want is to use `div` or `li`.

Any suggestion would greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Vertical centering without tables is tricky, but there're a few workarounds, see if you can use them:

http://www.student.oulu.fi/~laurirai/www/css/middle/
http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use some javascript codes in the `$(document).ready()` function for this
first you should use ID for all of your elements(2 description divs and one image div). after that, you can write some javascript code to obtain image by ID and retrieve its width attribute and then set this value for the width of both of your description divs
there is an HTML example:

```
<div id="desc1"><!-- some content --></div>
<div id="desc2"><!-- some content --></div>
<div id="image"><!-- some image --></div>
```

javascript should be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var width = $('#image')[0].attribute['width'];
    $('#desc1')[0].setAttribute('width',width);
    $('#desc2')[0].setAttribute('width',width);
});
```

by the way, you can use a special and equal name for both description divs and retrieve them by calling `$(document).getElementsByName('some_name')` method and then use a for loop. since you just have two divs to work with, it doesn't change in the performance

good luck;)

Answer (score -3):

Little bit of javascript would sort you out here, to set the DIVs on a line to equal heights.  There is a Jquery plugin to help you out here:

http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/